# Zend framework: Implementing Zend_acl

Tags: php, zend-framework, model-view-controller, acl

I am trying to implement `zend_acl`. I created a custom plugin and placed it in

`myzend/library/My/Controller/Plugin/Acl.php`

Where myzend is directory of my project. I am trying to initialize this custom plugin from `application.ini` using

```
autoloaderNamespaces[] = "My_"
resources.frontController.plugins.acl = "My_Controller_Plugin_Acl"
```

I am getting error message:

> Fatal error: Class 'My_Controller_Plugin_Acl' not found in
>   E:\wamp\www\myZend\library\Zend\Application\Resource\Frontcontroller.php
>   on line 117

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

did you register the plugin in your bootstrap ?

Add this to your bootstap.php file

```
protected function _initAcl() {
        $frontController = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
        $frontController->registerPlugin(new My_Controller_Plugin_Acl());
    }
```

Comment: i add this line in my bootstrap and its giving an error .. Fatal error: Class 'My_Controller_Plugin_Acl' not found in E:\wamp\www\myZend\application\Bootstrap.php on line 62

Comment: Fatal error: Class 'My_Controller_Plugin_Acl' not found in E:\wamp\www\myZend\application\Bootstrap.php on line 62

Comment: What have you called your class in myzend/library/My/Controller/Plugin/Acl.php & have you added the path to myZend to your application?

Comment: Sir how to add path myZend in application. I didn't get your point. Please explain